# How to set logo on each page with tikz?

Tags: latex, overleaf

I want to set my logo on each page except the front page. Right now I am able to do it on one page with the following:

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north east,inner sep=15pt] at (current page.north east){\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Figures/logo.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}

This sets the logo at the right place but just at one page. How do I repeat this for every page?

Comment: Please add a [mre] so we can which documentclass and packages you use. Depending on your class, there might already be a build in mechanism for a logo, e.g. beamer has the `\logo{...}` macro for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On semi up-to-date LaTeX, you can use hooks:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{The Title}
\author{First Last}
\date{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\clearpage
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north east,inner sep=15pt]
    at (current page.north east){\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-duck}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If for some reason you keep an old version of LaTeX, you might need to use one of the packages, e.g. [eso-pic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) or [background](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) etc.

EDIT. On the second thought, you might actually try `eso-pic` as it gives you more flexibility. Note with `eso-pic`, you could also use `savebox`es to create one instance of a logo upfront and only use its copy per each page--if you do so, remove `remember picture` or you will get warnings with redefined labels.

Consider one example below where you expect:

- no logo in on the first page (The Title)
- the first logog across the first chapter
- a clear second chapter, and
- the second logo across the last chapter.

and here's the code for the example

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{The Title}
\author{First Last}
\date{}

\newsavebox\logoone
\newsavebox\logotwo
\sbox\logoone{%
  \tikz[overlay]
  \node[anchor=north east, inner sep=15pt] at (current page.north east){%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}};}

\sbox\logotwo{%
  \tikz[overlay]
  \node[anchor=north east, inner sep=15pt] at (current page.north east){%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-duck}};}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{Chapter with the logo one}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\usebox\logoone}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Clear chapter}
\ClearShipoutPictureBG
\Blindtext

\chapter{Chapter with the logo two}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\usebox\logotwo}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```